# Merge Sort vs Bubble Sort vs Insertion Sort

Tags: c++, sorting

Among these three algorithms, which would be most efficient for sorting:

> 1.An arbitrary unsorted array
>
> 2.A reverse sorted array
>
> 3.An already sorted array

I know that for a general case, all three have equally bad time complexity. But that's not the question. Merge and Quick sort are beyond the scope of this question as well.

Comment: You mention "mergesort vs bubblesort vs insertion sort", but later you say mergesort is beyond the scope of this question. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Your previous title started with selection sort.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this link to try different combinations:
http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

You will see that:
1.) Arbitrary unsorted array: Insertion Sort, Merge
2.) Reverse sorted array: Insertion/Merge, Bubble not far behind
3.) Already sorted array: All are equal